# Is there a way to view which package source an installed NuGet package is from, in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

In Visual Studio's NuGet Package Manager, you can view which NuGet packages have been installed in a solution by clicking the "Installed" tab in the package manager.

However, in situations where the same package is in multiple NuGet Package Sources, it would be useful to see which package source a particular NuGet package has come from. Is there a way to see this in the NuGet Package Manager, or any where else in VS?

**Edit:**
Copying in my comment below for clarification:

I'm creating a project using a preexisting one as a model. Both projects will need to reference the same Nuget packages, so I open up the model project in Visual Studio, open the Nuget Package Manager, and look at its installed packages. The model project has "PackageA" installed. I open the new project, open the Nuget Package Manager for it, and Browse for "PackageA". I notice that "PackageA" is available in multiple Package Sources. (These are internal to my company, not nuget,org) In my new project, I'd like to install "PackageA" from the same Package Source as the model project

Comment: Are you asking how to determine which one of your dependencies installed a particular shared sub-dependency?

Comment: I'm creating a project using a preexisting one as a model. Both projects will need to reference the same Nuget packages, so I open up the model project in Visual Studio, open the Nuget Package Manager, and look at its installed packages.

The model project has "PackageA" installed. I open the new project, open the Nuget Package Manager for it, and Browse for "PackageA". I notice that "PackageA" is available in multiple Package Sources. (These are internal to my company, not nuget,org) In my new project, I'd like to  install "PackageA" from the same Package Source as the model project.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense... I have no idea personally how to do that, hopefully someone more knowledgeable will come by soon and answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to view which package source an installed NuGet package is from, in Visual Studio?

The simple answer is No. That is because the information about which NuGet packages have been installed in a solution by in the "Installed" tab in the package manager is based on the `packages.config` file. There are only package `ID, version, targetFramework` options in that file, so we could get the NuGet Package Sources info in the package manager based on the `Packages.config`.

Besides, when we use NuGet to manage our packages, NuGet will download the packages from the NuGet Package Sources and set those packages into the `Packages` folder in the solution folder. What we have to do next are related to the packages in the Packages folder rather than NuGet Package Sources (except NuGet restore, Restore just download the packages from NuGet Package Sources). So we could not find the package source only be based on a package which has been downloaded already without package source info in the Package.config.

What`s more, when we use NuGet to download the packages, NuGet will search the NuGet Package Sources one by one to download, NuGet **could not** be smart to store the Package Sources where each package download from.

> I'd like to install "PackageA" from the same Package Source as the model project

**To resolve this question**, you can open the Packages folder, copy "PackagesA", set it to the NuGet Package Source which you want to use, then install "PackageA" from that Package Source, you will get the same package as the model project.

Comment: "when we use NuGet to download the packages, NuGet will search the NuGet Package Sources one by one to download" This is good to know. If I understand you correctly, NuGet is agnostic about the source of a package; all that matters is the package ID, version, and target framework. That being the case, I shouldn't be concerned about installing the package from "the right package source"

Answer (score 6):

You asked for it! It just took 4.5 years.

Now (.NET 6 tooling) you do have a way to configure packages sources which is also called package source mapping:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6P38Dn69Ro
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/introducing-package-source-mapping/