# Find Nuget package source repository

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

In Visual Studio how do I find with 'Package Manager Console' or some other tool the source repository where specific package is available from?

```
find-package NLog
```

will only find package from one of the repository sources and display its version, but I don't know from which one is it coming from.

Comment: Is there a problem you're trying to solve? If so, what is it?  VS/PMC will use the list of sources/feeds in .nuget\NuGet.config (usually under each solution) when it restores/updates, etc. packages.  So, for starters, it's going to be from one of those sources

Comment: Also, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787914/is-there-a-way-to-view-which-package-source-an-installed-nuget-package-is-from); seems to be similar

Comment: @GreggL, yes, this question is very similar, but not exactly the same. That one is view which package source an installed NuGet package is from, means to obtain the package source of the package based on the downloaded package.

Answer (score 1):

> Find Nuget package source repository

According to the [Find-Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/ps-ref-find-package):

> Gets the set of remote packages with specified ID or keywords from the package source.

So, the default behavior of this command line is that search all package source, then only return `Package ID`, `Versions`, `Description` without package source of the highest version package.

Return result looks like:

```
Id                                  Versions                                 Description                                                                                                                                 
--                                  --------                                 -----------                                                                                                                                 
Newtonsoft.Json                     {11.0.1}                                 Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET                                                                              
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.0206440
```

**Fortunately**, there is a parameters **Source** of the syntax Find-Package, you can find the nuget package from the specified source, like:

```
find-package Newtonsoft.Json -source nuget.org
```

Or you just repeat the same command line `find-package NLog` with different package source selected in the Package Manager Console:

[image]

Hope this helps.